# Join stored procedure result with query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that contains a dynamic SQL query that passes a `FormId` to it and it returns its columns and their values.

Each form has different columns quantity and value so I can't make a temp table and pass the stored procedure result to it.

How can I join this stored procedure result with the rest of my SQL query?

This is my stored procedure:

```sql
declare @FormId tinyint = 1
declare @columns as varchar(max) = (select string_agg(quotename(ColumnName), ',') 
                                    from Paint_Form as f 
                                    inner join Paint_FormColumn as fc on fc.FormId = f.FormId 
                                    where f.FormId = @FormId)

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '

select * 
from 
    (select 
         f.FormId,
         fc.ColumnName,
         fce.CellValue
     from  
         Paint_Form as f 
     inner join 
         Paint_FormColumn as fc on fc.FormId = f.FormId
     inner join 
         Paint_FormCell as fce on fce.ColumnId = fc.ColumnId
     where 
         f.FormId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @FormId) + ') t
pivot
(
    max(CellValue) for ColumnName in (' + @columns + ')
) p
'

exec (@sql)
```

And I want something like this:

```
select * 
from report 
left join storedProcedure on formid
```

My tables:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oxMB.png)

Comment: When using Dynamic SQL you should still try to minimize the amount of SQL-in-strings - in this case, I see that a lot of the SQL in your `@sql` string could be moved out to a `FUNCTION` and only perform the final `PIVOT` step in Dynamic SQL. However, do you _need_ to use `PIVOT` in SQL here? Usually that's done within application code because if you `PIVOT` to dynamically-named columns you lose almost any ability to do any more processing of that data in T-SQL

Comment: I have do this because my data are horizontal and I wanted to vertical it.so I used PIVOT.

Comment: If you Know a simple way to vertical data in my tables please help me.

Comment: _"I have do this because my data are horizontal and I wanted to vertical it"_ - [**hold-up**](https://www.myinstants.com/en/instant/hold-up/) - show us your source table's `CREATE TABLE` and some sample data, because there's definitely going to be a better way to do this than using `PIVOT`.

Comment: I have added screenshot to my question you can see it.

Comment: **yikes** That's quite the EAV anti-pattern _disaster database_ you've got there... Is your org planning to fix this properly?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: #Dai I don't understand your mean.first screen shot is result set of my rest of query and second screenshot is pivoted result set.whta is disaster?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If your SP returns a dynamic resultset then I don't believe you can join it to anything. If its static you can insert it into a temp table and then join.

Comment: @fery I say it's a disaster because your screenshots showed your database is following [the EAV anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) which means your data is very, very, very difficult to process using Codd's relational model, which is the mathematical foundation for SQL (and "relational" does not mean "relationship" or "foreign key").

Comment: @fery You can start to fix things by introducing new `VIEW` objects (with `SCHEMABINDING`, of course) over your data for each defined form (assuming those form-definitions aren't dynamic) - then you can query that view _properly_. You don't need to use `PIVOT` in those views either, just lots of self-joins instead. _have fun_

Comment: no no Dai . it is a simple db that cointains 3 table {Form , Column , Cell) form has many columns and each columns has it's cell value. with two left and iner join I join them togheter.

Comment: @fery May I ask if you fully understood what I just wrote?

Comment: WHy do you want your data pivoted? What is using this data? Is it a report or an application or some kind of data export?

Answer (score 0):

You can join only tables that are base table (containing data) or view. In SQL Server you have two type of views : basic view that  needs a CREATE TABLE STATEMENT and parametric view that is an inline table function (UDF).

Stored procedures can return datasets. Datasets arn't tables. So you cannot use the name of a stored procedure to put it into the FROM clause of a query...

You have 2 possibilities for a workaround :

- acting outside the SP scope by creating a tamporary table, then
  insert the exec of the SP into, then use it in your final query
- acting inside the SP scope by adding the final query logic into the
  code of your SP

But I will certainly never do the first solution nor the second one and acquiesce to all the remarks that have been done like using views (without SCHEMABINDING) PIVOT operator if necessary...

Comment: _"But I will certainly never do the first solution nor the second one and acquiesce to all the remarks that have been done like using views (without SCHEMABINDING) PIVOT operator if necessary..."_ - Please elucidate.

Comment: @Dai transforming live data into static data with the ugly "...string_agg(quotename(ColumnName), ',') from Paint_Form as f ..." is an antipattern. Use a IN to compare directly to the SELECT without the STRING_SGG.

Comment: @SQLpro tnx man.So after these discussions and comments what is the best way to horizontal data from vertical data? from my data.

Comment: To do that outside the RDBMS in the tiers layer specialized to render data forms